# How I can filter a DataTable with DateTime Columns?

Tags: c#, listview, datatable, datarow

I want to filter a Datatable and it works but if I search a DateTime I get a error.

Here is my code. What wrong have I done?

```
 DataTable tb = DataBaseManager.GetRadiusDataTable(radiusconnectionstring, "marksullivan"); 

DataRow[] filteredRows = tb.Select("AcctStartTime LIKE '%" + searchstring + "%' OR AcctStopTime LIKE '%" + searchstring + "%' OR FramedIPAddress LIKE '%" + searchstring + "%'");
tb = filteredRows.CopyToDataTable();
this.ListView.DataSource = tb;
this.ListView.DataBind();
```

AcctStartTime:datetime
AcctStopTime :datetime
FramedIPAddress : varchar

```
The error: The Operation 'Like' could not to System.DateTime and System.String execute.
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Try to convert your date & time in string at the time when you fetching your data from DB....

Comment: why are we using same `SearchString` for all?

Comment: i make it with a mysql adapter

Answer (score 10):

Try like so [DateComparision in RowFilter](http://community.sgdotnet.org/blogs/chuawenching/archive/2007/03/29/C_2300_-DateTable.Select-_2D00_-DateTime-comparison-filter.aspx)

```
string filter = $"DateFrom > '{daDateFrom}' AND DateTo <= '{daDateTo}'";
tb.Select(filter)
```

Or from [DataRow filter Examples](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/)

> Date values are enclosed within sharp characters # #. The date format
> is the same as is the result of DateTime.ToString() method for
> invariant or English culture.

[C#]

```
dataView.RowFilter = "Date = #12/31/2008#"          // date value (time is 00:00:00)
dataView.RowFilter = "Date = #2008-12-31#"          // also this format is supported
dataView.RowFilter = "Date = #12/31/2008 16:44:58#" // date and time value
```